# Drag Multiple Objects Simultaneously

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

How do I drag multiple selected objects and move around within the frame?

The current implementation is whenever an user to click on object, by pressing the SHIFT key, each new object will be added into **multiShape**

However,I am only able to move single selected object instead.

My code is here:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent clickEvent) {

            clickShape = null;
            int x = clickEvent.getX(); // x-coordinate of point where mouse was
                                        // clicked
            int y = clickEvent.getY(); // y-coordinate of point

            if (clickEvent.isShiftDown()) {
                int top = shapes.size();
                for (int i = 0; i < top; i++) {
                    Shape s = (Shape) shapes.get(i);
                    if (s.containsPoint(x, y)) {
                        s.setColor(Color.RED);
                        multiShape.add(s);
                    }

                }

                repaint();
            } 

            }
        }
```

My moving object which is defined under abstract Shape class is as follow:

```
void moveTo(int x, int y) {
            left += x;
            top += y;
        }
```

mouseclick event:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent clickEvent) {
            if (dragShape != null) {
                return;
            }

            int x = clickEvent.getX(); // x-coordinate of point
            int y = clickEvent.getY(); // y-coordinate of point
            clickShape = null;
            for (int i = shapes.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) { // check shapes from
                                                            // front to back
                Shape s = (Shape) shapes.get(i);
                if (s.containsPoint(x, y)) {
                     dragShape = s;
                     prevDragX = x;
                     prevDragY = y;
                    clickShape = s;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // Continue from here
            if (clickShape == null) {
                return;
            } else if (clickEvent.isPopupTrigger()) {
                click.show(this, x - 10, y - 2);
            }  else {

                dragShape = clickShape;
                prevDragX = x;
                prevDragY = y;
            }

        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent clickEvent) {
            // User has moved the mouse. Move the dragged shape by the same
            // amount.
            if (dragShape == null) {
                return;
            }
            int x = clickEvent.getX();
            int y = clickEvent.getY();
            if (dragShape != null) {
            dragShape.moveTo(x - prevDragX, y - prevDragY);
            prevDragX = x;
            prevDragY = y;
            repaint(); // redraw canvas to show shape in new position
            }
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent clickEvent) {
            // User has released the mouse. Move the dragged shape, then set
            // shapeBeingDragged to null to indicate that dragging is over.
            if (dragShape == null) {
                return;
            }
            int x = clickEvent.getX();
            int y = clickEvent.getY();
            if (clickEvent.isPopupTrigger()) {
                click.show(this, x - 10, y - 2);
                // } else {
                dragShape.moveTo(x - prevDragX, y - prevDragY);
                if (dragShape.left >= getSize().width || dragShape.top >= getSize().height
                        || dragShape.left + dragShape.width < 0 || dragShape.top + dragShape.height < 0) { // shape
                    shapes.remove(dragShape); // remove shape from list
                }
                repaint();
            }
            dragShape = null;
        }
```

Comment: can you show your object moving method?

Comment: what Shape implementating classes are you using?

Comment: @FastSnail, I just updated my post with the method.

Comment: @ControlAltDel , it is an abstract shape class

Comment: @LattaLiPong hmm not that one. you should move all shapes in multiShape list

Comment: @FastSnail, forgive me if I didn't understand your message well. But the above method is the one making my object moveable.

Comment: Are you calling moveTo to all multiShape items?

Comment: @FastSnail, http://pastebin.com/nRmqYV3z

Comment: @LattaLiPong it's prvate make it public

Comment: @FastSnail, sorry it shall be available now

Comment: @Emd4600, are you telling me to change on the mouseDrag event class or all the related such as mouseRelease & mousePressed?

I got an error telling me that "cannot convert from element type Object"

Thanks

Comment: @FastSnail, did you manage to grab my code? Thanks.

Comment: You must change it in all events, so you always use multiShape, evne if you only selected one item.

Comment: @Emd4600, at this moment after i re-declaring the arraylist. I'm only able to select and move multiple objects but not longer for single object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling moveTo only to one shape, called dragShape, which is the last shape you get here

```
for (int i = shapes.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) { // check shapes from
                                                        // front to back
    Shape s = (Shape) shapes.get(i);
    if (s.containsPoint(x, y)) {
         dragShape = s;
         prevDragX = x;
         prevDragY = y;
         clickShape = s;
         break;
    }
}
```

Instead of doing:

```
if (dragShape != null) {
dragShape.moveTo(x - prevDragX, y - prevDragY);
```

Do:

```
for (Shape s : multiShape)
    s.moveTo(x - prevDragX, y - prevDragY);
```

Comment: I tried to change mouseDragged event and got an error.


`public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent clickEvent) {
   // User has moved the mouse. Move the dragged shape by the same
   // amount.
   if (dragShape == null) {
    return;
   }
   int x = clickEvent.getX();
   int y = clickEvent.getY();
   if (dragShape != null) {
   //dragShape.moveTo(x - prevDragX, y - prevDragY);
   //prevDragX = x;
   //prevDragY = y;
   for (Shape s : multiShape):
       s.moveTo(x - prevDragX, y - prevDragY);
   repaint(); // redraw canvas to show shape in new position
   }
  }`

Comment: for (Shape s : multiShape):. Remove the :, I've put it there by mistake xD

Comment: still the same error doesn't matter I removed the it or place it on any parts of the respective mouse events though :-(

Comment: I didn't mean to put that piece of code in all events. I mean to do the things you do to dragShape, but to all Shapes in multiShape instead.

Comment: Wait, that's not how ArrayLists are used. Do ArrayList<Shape> multiShape = new ArrayList<Shape>(); and ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>(); instead.

Comment: ehm.. I don't get it ><

Comment: Wait, is it working correctly for you now? Because it isn't for me xD

Comment: Gosh.. now i cant move the single object.. Only able to move the multiple selection.. ><

Comment: We'd better continue this on the chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87426/chat-between-emd4600-and-latta-li-pong